# Choosing between multiple action events

Tags: java, actionlistener, actionevent

So let´s just say I have 3 different ActionEvents and the class `ExecuteAction` should execute one of these event with the given integer `action`. `Int action` could be randomly generated or be given through a text field and all actionEvents should share the same Timer `actionTimer`.

Here´s a little concept of how I think it could work (It´s not a proper code, it´s just an idea).

```
public class ExecuteAction implements ActionListener{

private int action;
private Timer actionTimer = new Timer (delay, this);

   public ExecuteAction(){
       actionTimer.start();
       actionChooser(action);
      }

    private void actionChooser(int action){
         switch(action){
                case 1: //perform ActionEvent1 
                       break;
                case 2: //perform ActionEvent2
                       break;
                case 3: //perform ActionEvent3
                        break;
                   }
                }
}
```

Unfortunatly I don´t know how to handle it with the ActionListener and that´s where basically my ideas for this concept end. I would appriciate you helping me out finishing this concept.

Note: I don´t want to use any buttons, just the number should decide what actionEvent will be executed.

Comment: Why not use a plain vanilla ActionListener and use a Random object to help you choose a random number within it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the core Java pseudorandom number generator, `java.util.Random`, within your code, and random actions can be performed. If you place it within a standard ActionListener, then this can be called from within your Swing Timer. For example:

```
// imports

public class TimerFoo {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20; // or whatever delay desired
    private static final int MAX_CHOICE = 3;
    private ActionListener timerListener = new TimerListener();
    private Timer actionTimer;
    private Random random = new Random(); // import java.util.Random to use

    public ExecuteAction() {
        actionTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, () -> {
            int randomChoice = random.nextInt(MAX_CHOICE);
            switch (randomChoice) {
                case 0:
                    // do code for 0;
                    return;
                case 1:
                    // do code for 1;
                    return;
                case 2:
                    // do code for 2;
                    return;
                // don't need a default                 
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        actionTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.